# how to migrate a number of large sites from IIS 7 to IIS 8.5?

Tags: iis, migration

I have a number of large sites with thousands of images consuming few gigabytes each. We got a new server and I have to move all these sites there (old server will be decommissioned). What's the best way to do this and what I should be paying attention to?

Old server is Windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5
New server is Windows 2012 IIS 8.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I explored few options:

1. **IIS shared configuration** - did not work for me for some reason. I got DLL conflict errors saying that some .Net 7.5 module was not found. I guess that means I can export/import configuration only within the same IIS version? not sure. But at the end of the day I had to completely reinstall IIS on my new server - it just would not work after import. So I would not recommend this unless you know what you do.
2. **WebDeploy** - I think it could work for me - but due to the huge number of files and site size it was not able to ZIP the sites - or may be i was not patient enough. I guess it would work for smaller sites.
3. **XML export/import** - finally, I found [this article](http://www.microsoftpro.nl/2011/01/27/exporting-and-importing-sites-and-app-pools-from-iis-7-and-7-5/): it allowed me to export websites & app pool into XML and then import them on the new server. That worked beautifully:

> **Export**
>
> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppool /config /xml >
>   c:\apppools.xml
>
> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site /config /xml >
>   c:\sites.xml
>
> **Import**
>
> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /in < c:\apppools.xml
>
> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add site /in < c:\sites.xml

after that I only had to FTP my files to the new server - and I was good to go!

few things to remember:

1. Directory structure - keep it the same as on old server - no need to tweak XML files then
2. HTTPS certificates - don't forget to export them as well
3. Security - if you have assigned any special permissions to your sites' folders - make sure you re-create them on the new server
4. Additional IIS modules - like URL Rewrite - itemize and install them
5. Bindings - if you have wildcard ones, no need to worry but if your sites were bound to an IP address - use search/replace in sites.XML file to update it.