# Migrate IIS 6 to IIS 8.5 without using MS Deploy toolkit

Tags: web-services, iis, migration, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012

I am looking for a way to migrate IIS 6 to IIS 8.5 (server 2003 to server 2012 R2) web pages without using third-party applications or non-native tools like MS Deploy. The reason is so specific: I am a student and I have the challenge to migrate the web pages using only native resources.
I have searched on internet and I just found the MS Web Deploy tool and other alternatives just supported by server 2008 and 2012, like appcmd command.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021182/how-to-migrate-a-number-of-large-sites-from-iis-7-to-iis-8-5) on stackoverflow that points this alternatives:

- IIS shared configuration (It is not supported by IIS 6/Server 2003)
- WebDeploy (It is not a native tool)
- XML export/import using Appcmd (Appcmd is not available in server 2003)

So I am asking a new question. Is there any form to export/import web pages between IIS 6 and IIS 8.5?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear what you mean by a 'native tool'.  MSDeploy is provided by Microsoft and the IIS team suggests using this tool for migrating sites:

http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7-or-above

Comment: Hello, I mean a tool that you do not need to install or download from the internet. I mean a role or feature that I can enable and use to migrate or a command that can be used or an option on IIS Manager that i have not found.

Comment: I know It is so specific, but I need to do It this way. If there is no other option, my unique alternative is to create a new web page on the new server and then copy the directory files. I just asked on stackoverflow to be sure if it is possible or not to migrate the web pages the way I need to.